# Segmentation fault in MPI program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

Following is a program which aims to sum two matrices of size `128 * 128` splitting the tasks into `8` process, hence each process sums `16` rows of matrices.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int **matrixA;
    int **matrixB;
    int **resultMatrix = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(int *));

    if (rank == 0) {
       matrixA = generateMatrix();
       matrixB = generateMatrix();
       for (i = 0; i < COLS; i++)
          resultMatrix[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
    }

    int **auxA = malloc(16 * sizeof(int *));
    int **auxB = malloc(16 * sizeof(int *));
    int **auxC = malloc(16 * sizeof(int *));

    int i;
    int row, col;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
       auxA[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
       auxB[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
       auxC[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
    }

    MPI_Scatter(&(matrixA[0][0]), 16*COLS, MPI_INT, &(auxA[0][0]), 16*COLS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(&(matrixB[0][0]), 16*COLS, MPI_INT, &(auxB[0][0]), 16*COLS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    if (! gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname) == 0)
        perror("gethostname");

    for (row = 0; row < 16; row++)
    {
       for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
       {
           auxC[row][col] = auxA[row][col] + auxB[row][col];
       }
    }

    printf("Process Node %s %d\n done",hostname, rank);

    MPI_Gather(&auxC[0][0], 16*COLS, MPI_INT, &(resultMatrix[0][0]), 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
       printMatrix(resultMatrix);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Getting the following error message

```
[xxx115:12933] *** Process received signal ***
[xxx115:12933] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[xxx115:12933] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[xxx115:12933] Failing at address: 0x2
[xxx115:12934] *** Process received signal ***
[xxx115:12934] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[xxx115:12934] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[xxx115:12934] Failing at address: 0x2
[xxx115:12936] *** Process received signal ***
[xxx115:12936] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[xxx115:12936] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[xxx115:12936] Failing at address: 0x2
[xxx115:12933] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x32ff00f7e0]
[xxx115:12933] [ 1] ./hw5[0x400bd4]
[xxx115:12933] [ 2] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x32fe41ed1d]
[xxx115:12933] [ 3] ./hw5[0x400879]
[xxx115:12936] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x32ff00f7e0]
[xxx115:12936] [ 1] ./hw5[0x400bd4]
[xxx115:12936] [ 2] [wsu115:12933] *** End of error message ***
```

As i observe from other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275341/c-signal-code-address-not-mapped-1-mpirecv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108045/signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-mpi-c), segmentation fault arises when array makes an attempt to access memory out of its bounds.

However, i am not what part of program is causing this error. What can i do to fix the problem.

**EDIT**

After going through the comments, I realized that previous program was cluttered with lot of pointers. Here is a simplified version that is working without any error, but still not giving the expected output.

```
int **generateMatrix() 
{
    int **matrix = (int **)malloc(ROWS * sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
         matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) 
    {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) 
        {
            matrix[row][col] = col; 
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank, world_size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int **matrixA;
    int **matrixB;
    int resultMatrix[128][128];

    int auxA[16][128];
    int auxB[16][128];
    int auxC[16][128];

    if (rank == 0) {
        matrixA = generateMatrix();
        matrixB = generateMatrix();
    }

    MPI_Scatter(matrixA, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, auxA, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(matrixB, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, auxB, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    if (! gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname) == 0)
      perror("gethostname");

    int row, col; 
    for (row = 0; row < 16; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            auxC[row][col] = auxA[row][col] + auxB[row][col];
        }
    }

    printf("Process Node %s %d done\n",hostname, rank);

    MPI_Gather(auxC, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, resultMatrix, 16*COLS, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        printMatrix(resultMatrix);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: BTW, `malloc` can fail and then gives `NULL`

Comment: `mallo` may not be the problem. I tried to run the code without using MPI functionalities, with success.

Comment: But did you use the debugger when trying?

Comment: no i didn't...it is running without any issues, so didn't use debugger, but let me check with debugger too.

Comment: **Why** are you casting the return value of `malloc`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, because there seems to be confusion between C and C++.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Your code looks like C to me, so I removed the C++ tag. In C you don't have to cast the return of `malloc` and in C++ you wouldn't use it at all. Also C has proper 2D matrices, there is no need to fake them with arrays to pointers. Most of your problems will probably go away when you use proper types.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes i agree casting was redundent, wasn't aware about it.

Comment: @JensGustedt: using arrays to pointers to dynamically build 2D arrays

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: gcc- Wall -Wextra doesn't output anything. Still learning to use gbd with MPI

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I used the debugger and found the error. It was on MPI_Gather line. The argument after &resultMatrix is not correct. 
Now, the debugger is running the program correctly, but when i run on server i am still getting error.

Comment: MPI doesn't handle 2D arrays where each row is independently `malloc`'d. Use contiguous arrays instead, i.e. `int *a = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof *a);` You can create an index pointer array with elements that point to the beginning of each row in the contiguous memory in order to still use the convenient array syntax - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901671/1374437).

Comment: That is one of the differences between C and C++. C has dynamic arrays, so there is really no need for doing kruft like this.

Comment: @HristoIliev : Yes. But i am facing trouble in allocating values to matrixA and matrixB in generateMatrix function using contiguous pointers. The values that are to be assigned are in increasing order from 1 to 128, for every 128 rows.

Comment: You are still trying to scatter from an array of pointers to each row and this is NOT going to work. See the answer I've linked in my previous comment. It shows how to create an index into the contiguous memory so that you can use the `arr[x][y]` notation.

Comment: Yes, i figured out the correct way to do it. I am not sure what to do with the question now? There is no option to delete the question too, as i understand.